Backlit keyboard: does the illumination circuit still receive power when turned off?
I'm looking for a non-backlit keyboard. There are some, I found them, but since nowadays almost every keyboard comes with backlight in stock, I was wondering if the switch shuts it off completely.
Meaning by that to stop the power reaching the illumination circuit while using the keyboard.

that would depend on how the keyboard is designed ... would you expect all keyboards to be designed the same way?

It depends on the keyboard but if you're not turning the LED off with a physical switch, if you're pressing key combinations or software, that's a softswitch. The only keyboards I've seen with physical switches to control things like power are custom made.
The thing to remember is if something isn't receiving power then it's not using power; it doesn't matter what turned that power off.
If you're really stressed out about it then just buy a keyboard without LEDs, they do exist; I have a bunch.
